# Selenium Grid 2 does not support concurrency?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

It looks like SeleniumGrid2 can not start browser instances concurrently. So the following python script:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver


def start_firefox_remote():
    print datetime.now(), 'start firefox remote creation'
    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    capabilities['firefox_binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'
    browser = webdriver.Remote('http://10.0.2.149:4444/wd/hub',
                               desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    print datetime.now(), 'end firefox remote creation'


for i in xrange(5):
    time.sleep(.1)
    Thread(target=start_firefox_remote).start()
```

outputs the following:

```
2014-03-25 03:12:29.294335 start firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:29.395388 start firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:29.499435 start firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:29.600302 start firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:29.700916 start firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:31.806996 end firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:34.775233 end firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:37.948995 end firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:40.612055 end firefox remote creation
2014-03-25 03:12:44.301012 end firefox remote creation
[Finished in 15.2s]
```

As you can see, the browser instances creation processes begin at the same time, but then they  creates in sequence in non-concurrent mode. I'm using selenium-server-standalone 2.39.0. It's interesting that adding extra selenium nodes does not help also.

How can I run SeleniumGrid with real concurrency support?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your node config?

Comment: I start node with the following args: java -jar /home/smith/.selenium_server/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 50 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=50

Comment: And no any configuration besides.

Comment: WebDriver can't start more than a single Firefox instance on a node at once. It uses a locking mechanism to make sure that ports are allocated properly when starting multiple instance of Firefox on a machine. If you had multiple nodes connected to the same hub, this shouldn't be a problem.